# Deserialize a reqwest::Reponse to JSON but print response text on error

Tags: rust, ownership, serde, reqwest

I'm decoding a `reqwest::Response` to JSON. Usually that works fine, but in some rare cases the remote server returns a response that doesn't fit my `struct` that I'm using for deserialization. In those cases I'd like to print out the original response text for further debugging.

However, I'm having trouble to both do the JSON deserialization *and* printing out the response body. What I'd like to do is

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct MyData {
    // ...
}

async fn get_json(url: &str) -> Result<MyData, reqwest::Error> {
    let response = reqwest::get(url).await?;
    let text = response.text().await?;
    response
        .json::<MyData>().await
        .map_err(|err| {
            println!(
                "Could not decode response from {}: {}", url, text
            );
            err
        })
}
```

But that doesn't work because `response.text` takes `self`, so I cannot re-use `response` for `response.json`.

Based on [code from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65763005/857390) (also recommended [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528668/857390)) I've found this approach:

```rust
let response = reqwest::get(url).await?;
let text = response.text().await?;
serde_json::from_str(&text).map_err(...)
```

However, `serde_json::from_str` returns a `Result<_, serde_json::Error>`, so this approach would complicate my error handling because the calls before all return `Result<_, reqwest::Error>`. I'd prefer my function to also return the latter, not some custom error wrapper.

What is an idiomatic way of achieving my goal?

Comment: Regardless of what's idiomatic, what you'd prefer isn't possible: `reqwest` doesn't have a way to customize how json parsing is handled and it doesn't allow creating `Error`s outside the crate. So you *have* to use a different error type. Perhaps one of the many error-handling crates (`anyhow`, `thiserror`, `snafu`) can help ease that burden though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll get around the `.text()` and then `serde_json::from_str(&text)` part.

But you can avoid having to define custom error types by using the `anyhow` library (as kmdreko suggested in his/her comment). Simply use `Result<T, anyhow::Error>`, or equivalently `anyhow::Result<T>`, as the return type of any fallible function.

For example (copied from my codebase):

```rust
use anyhow::{Context, Result};
use reqwest::Client;
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use serde::Deserialize;
use url::Url;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct UrlPath<'a>(&'a str);

pub async fn get<T: DeserializeOwned>(
    client: &Client,
    backend_url: &Url,
    path: &UrlPath<'_>,
) -> Result<T> {
    let response = client
        .get(backend_url.join(path.0).with_context(|| {
            format!(
                "Unable to join base URL \"{}\" with path \"{:?}\"",
                backend_url, path
            )
        })?)
        .send()
        .await?;

    let contents = response.text().await?;
    serde_json::from_str(&contents).with_context(|| {
        format!("Unable to deserialise response. Body was: \"{}\"", contents)
    })
}
```

This will give you a nice error like this:

```
Error: Unable to fetch Source Kinds

Caused by:
    0: Unable to deserialise response. Body was: "{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}"
    1: invalid type: map, expected a sequence at line 1 column 0
```

`with_context()` from `anyhow` allows you to provide custom context to errors. And `anywhow` will convert most errors such that they "just work".

But only use this for application code, where you don't need to tell the caller what precisely went wrong.

More info: https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/index.html